# Creating a program that increments Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop

An integer array stores values 3,2,3,4,5. I am trying to create a program that increments these values by 2 and then saves the result into the same array using a `for` loop. I tried but something is wrong with my code, here:

```
public class ArrayClass {
  int a[] = {2, 3, 3, 4, 5};
}

public class ArrayObject {
  public static void main(String[] Ella) {
    int a[] = new int[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < a.length; i = i + 2) {
      a[i] = i + 2;
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please strive to post well-formatted code, meaning code that avoids multiple blank lines and that lines up well.

Comment: Unless you're required to use an explicit loop for some reason, this is exactly what `map` (the method) is useful for.

Comment: * im missing this ^ 
for(i=2;i<a.length;i=i+2){

Comment: You just take random statements and increment them by 2. That looks like brute force programming. Try to figure out what ``i`` really stands for.

Comment: If you want to increment the _value_(`a[i]`) by 2, why do you increment the _index_ (`i`) by 2? Incrementing the values would be `a[i] += 2;` and nothing more.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the OP obviously struggles with the basics, I wouldn't recommend lambdas here.

Comment: Your code also implies you want to increment the array `a` inside `ArrayClass`. In that case you need to create an instance of that class and then use the `a` field inside the loop, not the local `a` you're creating in `main()`.

Comment: @f1sh I don't know if it would be much more complicated. Lambdas are likely a new concept to them, but it would also simplify everything by reducing the entire loop to a single line of code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that is not the point. It might be shorter to write, but do you really want someone who never understood a ``for`` loop to enter the world of lambdas?

Comment: @f1sh Well, it would prevent him from doing things like incrementing the index twice as he had above, but I suppose he should learn how to use loops before worrying about abstractions over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that when you do `i = i + 2`, you are just incrementing the position index, not the actual value in that position.

you need to do:

`a[i] = a[i]+2;`

Let me explain what a[i] is:

```
|3|2|3|4|5|
 1 2 3 4 5
```

The first row are the values. The second row is the index. "Index" means the position number of each of positions in the array.

Another problem is that, when you initialise `i`, it need to be `i=0`. That is because `i` array indices (plural of index) always start from 0. That means that `a[0]` is the first position in the array That would be number 3 from your data set.

Comment: And also ``i`` should be initalized as ``0`` and not as ``2``.

Comment: And increment i only with 1.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] += 2;
  System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

You see, when increasing every single value of an array, the index has to be 0 and max the array's length. By adding one to i, the indexing of the array increases by one, which means the next number will be increased by two. what you did was add two to the "i" variable which means that only 3 of the varialbes would have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Please make below change to your code.It will work.

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i] = a[i] + 2;
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
```